# Totally bounded, why not automatically compact?

Tags: real-analysis

The definition for a totally bounded set given in my class is as follows:

> $A \subset M, (M,d)$ a metric space, is totally bounded if and only if $\forall \epsilon >0 $ there exists a finite cover for $A$ by $\epsilon$-balls; i.e. $n\in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}$ and $p_{1},p_{2},\dots, p_{n} \in A$ such that $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} B(\epsilon, p_{i})$.

My question is, how is this property different from finite sub covers of open covers? Shouldn't compactness automatically follow if $A\subset M$ is totally bounded? Why do we need the Lebesgue number property?

Answer (score 2):

Total boundedness is not sufficient to imply compactness because completeness is also required. For the example of $(0,1)$, this space is totally bounded but not complete because there are Cauchy sequences that don't converge (for example if the sequence approaches 0).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I am understanding this better (though not with respect to completeness like in the previous answer).

If my set has the Lebesgue number property, each open neighborhood about points in my set must be contained in some subset of my open cover, i.e. for $x\in A$, $B(\frac{\lambda}{2},x) \in U_{i}$ (where my open cover is $\mathcal{U}= \{ U_{i}|i\in I \}$) without $\lambda$ being dependent of my choice of $x$.

To use the same example as @Matt, the set $(0,1) \in \mathbb{R}$ with open covering $(\frac{1}{n},1), n\in \mathbb{N}\backslash \{0\}$ has no Lebesgue number because if I pick any point in my set, say $\frac{1}{4}$, I cannot guarantee that $B(\frac{\lambda}{2},\frac{1}{4}) \in U_{i}$ without choosing $\lambda$ with respect to $\frac{1}{4}$.